# Scala: abstract comparison method in trait

Tags: scala, comparison, abstract, traits

I have a trait with a size comparison function that I want to implement in a sublcass:

```scala
trait A {
    def isLessThan(that: A): Boolean
    ...
}
```

```scala
class SubOfA() extends A {
    ...
    override def isLessThan(that: SubOfA): Boolean = {
        this.size < that.size
    }
    ...
}
```

However, the method isn't a valid override because the argument type is `SubOfA` and not `A`.

---

I've also tried making the argument type `this.type`, but then when I am calling the method from an abstract setting I can't use an object of type `A` as the argument:

```scala
...
(foo: A, bar: A) => foo.isLessThan(bar)
```

This would expect type `foo.type` and not `A` which are the same but I don't think the compiler knows that yet.

---

Any ideas of how I could get something like this to work? I've looked all over the place to find an answer to this, but can't find anything.  Maybe I don't know what is the right question to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the first method with:

```
class SubOfA() extends A {

    override def isLessThan(that: A): Boolean = that match {
        case that : subOfA =>  this.size < that.size
        case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Wrong comparison") //or whatever behaviour deemed suitabe here
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah, I should have known that pattern matching would fix it, as with most things in Scala!   If starting from scratch, I think Luis' answer is probably better to go with for scalability, but this is a good way of fixing the problem quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use `F-Bounded` **polymorphism** *(which would the solution on **Java**)*, or `Typeclasses` **polymorphism** *(which would be the solution on **Haskell**)*.
My personal preference is to use typeclasses, because it is more extensible, maintainable & more typesafe - [Here](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) is more objective comparison by Rob Norris.

### F-Bounded.

```
trait Comparable[A <: Comparable[A]] { this: A =>
  def isLessThan(that: A): Boolean
}

class SubOfComparable extends Comparable[SubOfComparable] {
  val size: Int = ???
  override final def isLessThan(that: SubOfComparable): Boolean =
    this.size < that.size
}
```

### Typeclasses.

```
trait Comparator[T] {
  def isLessThan(a: T, b: T): Boolean
}

object syntax {
  object comparator {
    implicit final class ComparatorOps[T](val self: T) extends AnyVal {
      final def < (that: T)(implicit C: Comparator[T]): Boolean =
        C.isLessThan(self, that)
    }
  }
}

class Sub {
  final val size: Int = ???
}

object Sub {
  implicit val SubComparator: Comparator[Sub] = new Comparator[Sub] {
    override final def isLessThan(a: Sub, b: Sub): Boolean =
      a.size < b.size
  }
}

import syntax.comparator._
val a = new Sub(...)
val b = new Sub(...)
a < b
```

Comment: I found some information on F-Bounded polymorphism [here](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#self-recursive-type) while doing my initial search, but I ended up not doing it because I am already using the trait in a lot of other places that I would have to go through and refactor to add the type parameter. This is definitely the more elegant way of doing it though.